# Lightning Datatable Action Violates Content Security Policy directive

Tags: lightning, datatable, action

I'm using Lightning Datatable with Static Actions and following the guide in [Developer Salesforce.com Lightning Datatable component guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) but getting the following error (seen in the Chrome developer console) when I try to select the any of the actions:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'nonce-f1a6077e-ac22-4495-b083-239f808d8e4c' chrome-extension:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://sfdc.azureedge.net
>   *.cs85.visual.force.com https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is
>   present in the source list.

The code I have:

Component:

```
    <aura:component controller="OSS_SupplierController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <!-- attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <!-- handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

     <lightning:card>    
        <div class="c-container">

            <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
            <div style="height: 300px">
                <lightning:datatable
                        keyField="id"
                        data="{! v.data }"
                        columns="{! v.columns }"
                        onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                        hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
    ({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('init with record id ' + component.get("v.recordId"));
        var action = component.get('c.getResponsibleContacts');
        action.setParams({ftsSupplierId : component.get("v.recordId") });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(component.isValid() && response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                var responsiblePersons = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.data",responsiblePersons);
            }else{
                console.log("Error while responsiblePersons");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

         var actions = [
            { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
            { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
            { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
        ];

        component.set('v.columns', [
            {type:  'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } },
            {label: 'name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}, 
            {label: 'email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'text'} 
        ]);
    },

    handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
})
```

Apex is simply:

```
    public with sharing class OSS_SupplierController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getResponsibleContacts(Id ftsSupplierId)
    {
        List<Contact> responsibleContacts;

        if (ftsSupplierId != null){
            //get account
            FTS_Supplier__c ftSupplier = [SELECT ID, Supplier_account__c from FTS_Supplier__c where id=:ftsSupplierId];

            responsibleContacts = [SELECT Id, Name, FTS_Job_Title__c, FTS_Role__c, Email, Phone, MobilePhone, FTS_Address__c
                                  FROM Contact where AccountId=:ftSupplier.Supplier_account__c];

        }
        return responsibleContacts;
    }    
}
```

At present allow I have in the handleRowAction is a simple console log as just simply want to prove I am getting there, but getting an error as show above as soon as I select any of the actions.

Comment: I am getting this as well.  The error occurs after my JS code has completed.  It doesn't affect the functionality, it is acting as some kind of warning.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. It looks like some XSS protection built into Aura that is being triggered by inline code on the row of the `datatable`. The JS code to call the action is being injected directly into markup. `<a href="javascript:void(0)"`. That's a big no-no and Salesforce needs to do something about this.